# .Net Core and SSL jet possible with StreamSocket/RESTful/SignalR as Server/Client?

Tags: rest, ssl, win-universal-app, .net-core, windowsiot

I ask my self if there are any ways to send data per SSL encrypted on an UWP. Because I have to send DATA encrypted from a Raspberry Pi 3 (Windows IoT) to an server.

Does anybody know if it is possbile? And if can you send me a link to a sample/tutorial? THX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In UWP, you can use different technologies to send SSL data. If you need to communicate in HTTPS, Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient would be the best choice, as it provides best capabilities in terms of SSL (more details [here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/11/23/demystifying-httpclient-apis-in-the-universal-windows-platform/)). You can also use secure sockets as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/mt280233#______________________) (also the sample code for using secure sockets is available in [UWP Samples on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket)).

Comment: Thx the "await socket.ConnectAsync()" (StreamSocket) worked!

Comment: @Philip nice to hear that! I suggest you also accept the answer as correct, so that more people can find it useful.